# How to display the icon, if a table has a value called Accessories, then this value Accessories should replace with the icon in angular

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ug3k.png)All the Accessories values should replace`enter code here`

```
enter code here
```

<p-table [value]="products">`enter code here`
`enter code here`
`enter code here`
Code`enter code here`
Name`enter code here`
Category`enter code here`
Quantity`enter code here`
`enter code here`



{{product.code}}
{{product.name}}
{{product.category}}
{{product.quantity}}

Comment: put if condition like (product.category == "Accessories") then set icon else pass the value

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This place is here to get help if you are  stuck not to get your work done.

Comment: @Codebrekers It works, Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add if condition in your code

```
  if(product.category == "Accessories")
      // set your icon
  else
      // pass your regular value
```

Comment: @Aleti av : if my comment helps you, please accept the answer, and upvote if is really helpful to you.